# Swift variable declaration with closure

Tags: swift, variables, closures, declaration

I saw a declaration which confuses me. ( the grammar here)

```
static var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter
}()
```

To declare a variable, it looks like it uses a function(initializer) to create one. 
Since I am not familiar with closure in Swift, I found some useful tutorial. However, the example above seems to not fit in any of them.
ref: http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com/
Any suggestions, references, or tutorial will be appreciated.

Comment: That closure is a method that returns a NSDateFormatter object

Comment: `{ ... }` ← creates a closure instance which has no argument and returns a `NSDateFormatter`, and `()` ← invokes the closure with no argument and gets the `NSDateFormatter` the closure created.

Comment: It sounds like I can simply replace those codes within closure to initializer?
I tried this, but Xcode complains " 'class var' declaration requires an initializer expression or getter/setter specifier "

Comment: Edit your question to include the complete code that's giving you the error in your comment. Any initializer (like `NSDateFormatter()`) should work in that you can say `var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()` or `...= theReturnValueOfSomeClosure()` if you need to initialize *and further configure* the result *before assigning it* to the property.

Comment: fuckingclosuresyntax.com is no good, the author is too green. Mike who did the fuckingblocksyntax.com is really good though!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Syntax

As @findall said in the comments, you are basically creating a function and executing it.

To clarify the syntax, I'll try to create an example in JavaScript.

Consider this code snippet:

#### Example #1

```
//creates a global variable
var globalString = "Very important global string";
```

This string will be created and stored in memory as soon as this line of code is interpreted. Now compare it to this other implementation:

#### Example #2

```
//also creates a global variable 
var globalString = function() {
    return "Very important global string";
};
```

The second implementation does not create a string, but creates a function that ultimately produces a string.

In Swift, when you declare a variable with the `{...}()` syntax, you are actually doing something similar to **Example #2**.

---

### Use case

When would it be useful to declare a variable in such way? When the declaration would require some extra setup to take place.

In the example posted in the question, an NSDateFormatter may need a few extra steps to be instantiated the way your app expects it to behave. In other words:

```
class ThisClass {
    //if you do this, you'll then have to configure your number formatter later on
    static var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    
    func userFormatter() {
        //you probably want this setup to take place only once
        //not every time you use the formatter
        ThisClass.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    
        //do something with the formatter
    }
}
```

This example is quite nicely replaced by:

```
class ThisClass {
    static var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    func userFormatter() {
        //do something with the formatter with no setup needed!
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use the {...}() format to declare a variable or constant, does that closure only get run once when the variable or constant is declared, or is it run each time the variable or constant is accessed?

Comment: It’s executed only once